# When to hide iAd/AdMob banners

Tags: ios, admob, iad

What are the best practices for when to manually hide iAd/AdMob banners? Do I need to hide them when backgrounding the app, showing a modal view, or bringing up the keyboard? Or do I not need to worry about any of that because they take care of not displaying new ads, etc on their own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should hide any banners any time they are covered over or don't have content.  Failure to do so can reduce the returns on your ads..